# change pointer of char[] in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I had to write a program that declares `char text[16];` and `int number;` and then fills it with input from the user. Then I have to call another function (without passing anything) and recall that data from the stack and display it.
I was able to find both of them

```
// This is the function that is called without passing any variables
int   number; 
char  text[16];

cout << *(&text + 5) << endl; // This outputs the correct text but I can not figure out how to assign it to text
number = *(int*)(&number + 20); // This works and outputs the correct number and saves correctly to int number;


cout << "\tnumber: "
  << number
  << endl;
cout << "\ttext:   "
  << text
  << endl;
```

I would like to know if there is a way to transfer the text from `*(&text + 5)` to `char text[16];`

Comment: Yes, you can try `text[1] = *(&text + 5)`. You can store this value in this way. or `strcpy()`

Comment: If you don't want to change the text you can also just declare another pointer to char and assign the address of the original text "up the stack" to it (because that address won't change during the run time of this function): `const char *upstacktext = *(&text + 5);`  (Or, simpler, probably `const char *upstacktext = text + 80;`.) That way you emulate passing the address of the original char array as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is going to result in undefined behavior. Depending heavily on the compiler and therefore in turn on the architecture.  The proof being that when I compile and run your code with different optimization flags I get different results. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

The first expression `*(&text + 5)` evaluates to taking the address of the `text` pointer in memory, adding 5 to it and then dereferencing that to get a character value that is stored at that location.  This can be pretty much anything on the stack at that time.

`&number + 20` will definitely go off the "visible" stack, this is pointer arithmetic and will result in you adding `20*sizeof(int)` to the pointer to the memory address of `number` on the stack.

If this is what you are intending to do then you should probably use strcpy as suggested by @JafferWilson

Comment: It was. I had to locate the item on the stack and dereference it and save it to the variable. From your explanation, I feel like I am going about this problem incorrectly. Any suggestions?

Comment: One question. Which item on the stack did you want to fetch?

Comment: The the two variables from the other function. I have locate the variables from another function.  *(&text+5) is the location on the stack of the variable I need to pull.

Comment: I do not think this is the right way to pull the value of the variable on the other stack.  To do this you should pass in the address of the other variable to this function as an argument and then read from it.

Comment: If you are trying to investigate the layout of your stack and what other values are on it at runtime then go ahead! Analyze what is going on all you want.  You would also probably want to look at the compiled assembly code from your C++ source in that case :) That should give you better intuition about what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments on the answer by Curious the answer is:

There is no proper way to read local variables in another function in C++ without passing them (or pointers to them or references to them) as parameters (or within objects you pass as parameters).

You can assign file scope (so called global) variables and read them in other functions. That is almost always a bad idea.

I get the feeling you might be coming from an assembler programming background to even try this sort of thing. You need to surrender a bit more to the structured programming paradigm.